# <w>[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy]Serializing big strings(101kiB)impacts deserialization performance(consider using Buffer instead&decode when n

Tags: javascript, mongodb, webhooks, mern

something wrong with my mongoDB connection or clerkid or webpack. its not fetching userids and also showing // This is a native JavaScript error (e.g., TypeError, RangeError)
17 |     console.error(error.message);

> 18 |     throw new Error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
> |          ^
> 19 |   } else if (typeof error === "string") {
> 20 |     // This is a string error message
> 21 |     console.error(error);        please let me know how to solve this

i want to resolve this problem its related to mongodb connection in atlas and clerkif and webhooks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.